# last -t command HELP

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix

I want to use 'last -t' and then pass the current date/time to it in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format like it asks. the only way i know how to get the current date/time is through 'date' but it passes it back in the wrong format than needed.

also last-t uses a time frame to show who has logged in since time frame, how would i go about subtracting 1 min from the current time when i do get it into the right format.

and finally is there a command that shows those who logged out as well?

Comment: What OS are you on?  In BSD `last -t` filters by TTY, but you appear to think that you have a `last` that can filter by time.

Comment: @Nick: A quick google found this: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?last

Comment: im testing it on Ubuntu lastest version. and last -t on my man page asks for YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised actually on Ubuntu and Cent OS, the `last -t` actually behaves as showing logins `up till` the time specified, as opposed to `as of` the time specified as stated in its man page.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `date` manpage. You can output the date and time in all kinds of formats, including the one you want. Remember to quote the argument.

For subtracting 1 minute, personally I'd use Python and the `datetime` module, it's easy to do time calculations with it.

Don't know about the logout part.

Comment: this is for a class requiring a shell script to perform this. it's not for true functionality=/

Answer (score 0):

```
1       NOW=`date`
2       MINAGO=$((-1 + `date -d "$NOW" "+%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S" | cut -d: -f2 `))
3       MINAGO=`printf "%02i" $MINAGO`
4       MINAGO=`date -d "$NOW" "+%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S"| sed s/:.*:/$MINAGO/`       
5       last -t $MINAGO
```

1. store time in NOW
2. print NOW as YYYYMMDDHH:MM:SS and extract MM, add -1, store in MINAGO
3. pad with zeros up to length 2 (last -t asks for 08 min not 8), store in MINAGO
4. print time from NOW and replace the minute part with MINAGO, store in MINAGO
5. call last with YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

You will have to be more specific about what you mean by showing those who logged out, because last is showing you who logged out and when they did it. If they are not still logged in they are out. What more do you need to know? Anyway, it's possible to look for real accounts in /etc/shadow and remove from that list users who are still logged in. 
for example:

```
getent shadow |sort -t: -k2,2 | awk -F: '($2 !="*") && ($2 !="!") { print $1 }'
```

keep in mind that only root can read /etc/shadow

---

scratch the above;

```
last -t $( 
          date -d @$(( -60 + `date +%s` )) +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
          )
| grep still
```

e.g

```
$ last -t $( date -d @$(( -60 + `date +%s` )) +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) | grep still
*    pts/4    *  Sat Sep  7 02:20   still logged in
*    pts/44   *  Fri Sep  6 19:08   still logged in
*    pts/8    *  Fri Sep  6 11:26   still logged in
*    pts/32   *  Fri Sep  6 09:37   still logged in
*    pts/60   *  Wed Sep  4 08:06   still logged in
*    pts/34   *  Tue Sep  3 23:26   still logged in
*    pts/5    *  Tue Sep  3 12:38   still logged in
*    pts/37   *  Mon Sep  2 10:59   still logged in
*    pts/46   *  Sun Sep  1 21:29   still logged in
```

Comment: Step 2 might get interesting if it happens to be 17:00 (or any other time where `%M` gives 0 for an output)...